# FromSqlRaw not working for me in .net 6. 'FromSqlRaw' or 'FromSqlInterpolated' was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net-6.0

I have a query that is working on .Net 3. After I upgraded to .Net 6, it isn't working anymore. I tested the query in SQL and it was working but I can't translate into Linq - it gives me this exception:

> 'FromSqlRaw' or 'FromSqlInterpolated' was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it.
> Consider calling 'AsEnumerable' after the method to perform the composition on the client side.

```
string sqlCheckAllParents = @";WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT Id, ParentId, Published, IsDeleted 
    FROM Comments h 
    WHERE Id = {0} 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p.Id, p.ParentId, p.Published, p.IsDeleted 
    FROM
        Comments p 
        INNER JOIN
            cte c ON c.parentId = p.Id 
)
select Id from cte m where IsDeleted = 1 or Published = 0";

            var dontAllowLoadData = await _comments.FromSqlRaw(sqlCheckAllParents, parentId ?? 0).Select(x => x.Id).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (dontAllowLoadData.Any())
            {
                return new DataGridViewModel<Comment>
                {
                    Records = new List<Comment>(),
                    TotalCount = 0
                };
            }
```

Database provider: (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer)
Target framework: (.NET 6.0)

Calling `.AsEnumerable()` doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: I wonder how it has worked previously, I thought that [the limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#limitations) of _"the SQL query must return data for all properties of the entity type."_ was always present. Though .NET Core 3 was a long time ago.

Comment: i dont know
the last guy that wrote these is not available and I'm trying to make this work again

Comment: Update EF Core to 7th version and use `context.Database.SqlQuery<int>(query).ToListAsync()`.